# Combine Publisher not firing for a KVO property

Tags: ios, macos, combine, avaudioengine

I'm trying to track an AVAudioPlayerNode's playback state via its Combine Publisher:

```swift
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import Combine

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        cancellable = player.publisher(for: \.isPlaying)
            .sink { newValue in
                print("is playing: \(newValue)")
            }

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blues", withExtension: "aiff")!
        let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)

        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))!
        try! file.read(into: buffer)

        engine.attach(player)
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: file.processingFormat)

        player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)

        try! engine.start()
        player.play()
    }
}
```

The sink gets called just once when it's initialised, and never again. I would expect it to get called when playback starts, but it doesn't... Any ideas why?

Comment: Is the `isPlaying` property KVO-compliant? Normally the docs mention explicitly when properties are KVO-compliant but the docs for `AVAudioPlayerNode` don't address it directly.

Comment: [the docs for `isPlaying`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayernode/1390631-isplaying) are silent as to its KVO-compliance.. supposing this means that it's not KVO compliant, then why is there a `publisher` for it?

Comment: Mostly supposition but I assume that `NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher` works for all ObjC `@property` declarations whether or not the ObjC class internally handles the property in a KVO-compliant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVAudioPlayerNode` does not seem to be KVO-compliant for the `isPlaying` property. Normally the docs mention explicitly when properties are KVO-compliant but the [docs for AVAudioPlayerNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayernode/1390631-isplaying) don't address it directly

I ran a simple test using `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:options:context:)` and confirmed that KVO notifications are not emitted when `play()` or `stop()` is called.

As for why the Combine publisher exists, I assume that `NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher` works for all ObjC `@property` declarations whether or not the ObjC class internally handles the property in a KVO-compliant way (by sending `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:`).